# How to log events in RTEMS 6?

Tags: c++, c, real-time, rtems

What's the simplest way in RTEMS 6 to log events in tasks and their timestamp?

E.g.

```
rtems_task Foo_task(
  rtems_task_argument task_index
)
{
  // log here

  rtems_semaphore_obtain(sem);
  // log here

  foo();

  rtems_semaphore_release(sem);
  // log here

  ...
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I would allocate the mmeory for the message,  create it, and queue it (best reference) to the log task.

Comment: @0___________ can you provide an example or pseudocode in an answer? I'm new to rtems and real-time os in general. Thanks.